# How to retrieve data from serialize with Foreach PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have Form inside Jquery Ajax like this

```
 $.post("http://10.2.15.100/source.php", function(response){

     //alert(JSON.stringify(response));   

     var arr = $.parseJSON(response);
     var trHTML = "";

     $.each(arr, function(ix, nilai){
        trHTML +='<li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false" data-corners="false"><h2>'+ arr[ix].ITEM_NAME +'</h2><br><input name="ITEM_NAME[]" class="ITEM_NAME" value="'+ arr[ix].ITEM_NAME +'" type="text">Last 3 Month<input name="bln_akhir[]" class="bln_akhir" value="'+ arr[ix].LAST_3MON +'" type="text">Forcast<input name="FORECAST[]" class="FORECAST" type="text"><input name="ITEM_CODE[]" class="ITEM_CODE" value="'+ arr[ix].ITEM_CODE +'" type="text"><br>%<input name="PERSEN[]" class="PERSEN" type="text"><br>Bulan 1<input name="BULAN1[]" class="BULAN1" type="text"><br>Bulan 2<input name="BULAN2[]" class="BULAN2" type="text"><br>Bulan 3<input name="BULAN3[]" class="BULAN3" type="text"></li>'
     });//end each

    // $('#datane').append(trHTML).listview("refresh");
    $('#datane').append(trHTML);
    $('#datane').trigger("create");         
});//end post
```

it has success get data from serialize Form.

and this on **PHP**

$data = $_POST['data'];

```
 foreach($data as $item){
    $month = date('M');
    if($item['FORECAST'] != ""){
        if($item['TRIWULAN'] != ""){
            $sql_kj = "INSERT INTO kj SET 
                        TGL = '$tanggal',
                TRIWULAN = '".$item['TRIWULAN']."',
                BULAN_INPUT = '$month',
                NAMA_DIST = '$_SESSION[USER]',
                ID_PRODUK = '".$item['ITEM_CODE']."',
                NAMA_PRODUK = '$nama_produk',
                ITEM_CODE = '".$item['item_code']."',
                DAERAH     = '$_SESSION[KOTA]',
                HARGA = '$harga',
                BLN_AKHIR = '".$item['bln_akhir']."',
                FORECAST = '".$item['FORECAST']."',
                PERSEN   = '".$item['PERSEN']."',
                BULAN1   = '".$item['BULAN1']."',
                BULAN2   = '".$item['BULAN2']."',
                BULAN3   = '".$item['BULAN3']."',
                TOTAL_VALUE    = '$total_value[$isi]',
                SET_BLN1 = 'ISI',
                ACCOUNT_ID = '27660'";

            echo json_encode($sql_kj);
            $hasil_input_kj = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kj);
        }
    }
}
```

and **ajax for insert**

```
 $("#SAVE").on("click",function(){
    var data = $("#FORMX2").serialize();
    $.post("http://10.2.15.100/source_input.php", data, function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert(data);               
        /*if(data.status == "sukses"){
             alert('Input Berhasil');
             window.location='index.html';
           }
           else if(data.status == 'gagal'){
              alert("Error on query!");
           }*/
    });


});
```

my question: Is anything wrong on my Code? because it still cant insert to database.

This the Screen Shot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: Not sure where `$data` some from, but if it's user-supplied, you have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Your error is coming from two lines before the start of the PHP code you shared

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara lets talk SQL injection soon, now insert is more important

Comment: @RobbieAverill I will check your suggested

Comment: not work I think the problem is inside foreach, Any Idea?

Comment: The problem is that you're never setting `$data` before you do `foreach($data as $item)`.

Comment: @Barmar I have setting, but I forget to post it. $data = $_POST['data']; that my Setting. it that wrong?